# Disallow JVM system security policy settings override

Tags: security, permissions, java, tls, restrictions

I've defined some parameters to file `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-8-oracle-x64/lib/security/java.security` to comply JAVA security settings with our security policy.
Some parameter I have edited are

```
security.overridePropertiesFile=false
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms= ...
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2,...
```

It is unclear to me if a developer could set custom parameter in an application, does the JVM enforce these parameters or can they be overridden ?

I've seen there this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830685/how-to-enforce-a-security-policy-for-each-and-every-executing-java-program/21009157#21009157) already about Java security Policy but I'm my case I just want the system-policy to be applied.

Comment: To prevent users overwrite security settings you can create a [policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) that only allow read [security properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html#SecurityPermission).

Comment: @FedericoSierra it seems to be code-related (I've updated the question), and my question was certainly unclear. I rephrased it.

Comment: To prevent users from specifying additional policy files, you can set the `policy.expandProperties` property to false, remove the users `.java.policy` entry, and makes the `java.security` file read only by the end users. With this you can established a sanbox that cannot be modified by end users.

Comment: Can I find some example code to run to validate the enforcement is respected ?